# binding lua in static library segfault

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to bind a C++ (functional) lua extension as a static library to a host C++ program.
I made a minimalistic program to see if it's going to work properly. I currently have this code:

main.cpp :

```
#include "util.h"

int main()
{
    lua_State* L;
    startLua(L);//after the call to this is gets the segfault
    luaL_dofile(L,"test.lua");
}
```

util.h :

```
#ifndef _UTIL_FILE_INCLUDED_
#define _UTIL_FILE_INCLUDED_

extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
}


//functions
int startLua(lua_State* start);

#endif
```

util.cpp :

```
#include "util.h"

int startLua(lua_State* start)
{
    //program never gets here
    start = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile :

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -fpermissive 
LFLAGS=-llua


all: util.a main.o 
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) main.o util.a -o main
util.a: util.o util.h
    ar -cvq util.a util.o
util.o: util.cpp util.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) util.cpp
main.o: main.cpp util.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o *.a
```

I also tried undefining L from the header and defining it purely inside of main(), with same result.

the only warning I get during compile is that "L is defined but not used" or "L is used uninitialized".

at runtime it starts by giving me out a segfault right away.

I don't exactly work with libraries that often, so it may be a fault there, in that case this should be a simple question.

In case it matters, I use gcc 4.7.2, lua 5.1.5 and Arch Linux (updated).

EDIT: According to GDB, the problem is here:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bb6390 in lua_gettop () from /usr/lib/liblua.so.5.1

I never had problems with lua, is it possible that compiling it into a static library is a mistake?

Comment: The question is, does `start = lua_open();` get `start` to be initialized? Does it even get that far?

Comment: @TonyTheLion added std::cout calls before each action, putting a comment in the code here for where it got.

Comment: @TonyTheLion ran it through debugger, the place with the error is quite strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lua_State* L;
startLua(L);//after the call to this is gets the segfault
```

This is a basic C problem here. You *cannot change* the value of parameters in C when they are passed by value.

`startLua` sets the value of its parameter. But that doesn't affect `L` at all. This isn't C++ (and even if it were, you didn't pass it by *reference*). If you want to affect `L`, then you must pass a pointer to `L` itself. As in `&L`, and `startLua` has to take a `lua_State**`. And to set the value, it must dereference the pointer (`*start = lua_open()`).

Or even better, just do this:

```
lua_State *L = startLua();
```

And have `startLua` *return* the Lua state.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is supposed to be a larger library that would manipulate an array of pointers, have to ask, are pointers to pointers to pointers technically legal?

Comment: @Shingetsu: "*are pointers to pointers to pointers technically legal*" You can have `ObjectType************`'s if you want. Now granted, why you would need "pointers to pointers to pointers" when you're claiming to use *C++* is beyond me. You are aware of things like `std::vector` and so forth, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, I simply prefer the C way. I just happen to be using a C++ library, I just keep to the C conventions whenever possible.

Comment: This might be of interest for you then: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/8/18/beautiful-native-libraries/